# When authenticating with a JWT should custom scope(permissions/claims) go in access token or id token?

Tags: authentication, jwt, auth0

When authenticating with a JWT should custom scope(permissions/claims) go in access token or id token? Seen it done both ways but not sure what is best practice.

Comment: Depends on the rest of your logic and use case. Does your server code rely on the jwt's permissions / claims? If you update a user's permissions / claims, do you update the user's jwt if they are already logged in?

Comment: It does rely on permissions/claims in the token like read:foobar. Not updating token once authN

Comment: Then are you fine with a user whose permissions were altered while logged in to perform possible unauthorized actions? Most people wouldn't won't that. Not sure if you are trying to reduce the calls to the db but unless you having performance issues, don't try to pre-optimize.

Comment: wouldnt that make the signature invalid?

Comment: It depends on the rest of your logic and use case. When your server decrypts the jwt and retrieves the user id, etc, it should run a query to check for user permissions, claims, etc and save it to the context for the rest of your server functions to use. Its usually one query with one or more joins.

Comment: How is your signature getting invalidated?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the second call if possible/secure. By changing the content of the token that was issued by auth server, that would make the signature invalid. The bad actor would need the signing key and at that point Ive got bigger problems lol

Comment: I never mentioned to alter the jwt. I'm not familiar with auth0 either. Does auth0 return user id and the latest permissions / claims or do you manage permissions / claims on your db?

Comment: yes it does, they are included in the tokens payload data

Comment: If auth0 is managing your user, permissions, and claims info, then aren't you getting the latest security info when validating the jwt with auth0?

Comment: yeah, the original question is asking if theres a best practice where to put that info - access token or id token- both of which are jwts capable of carrying the information. Or should I should validate the token, then make another api call to auth0 to get permissions and such

Comment: According to auth0, you shouldn't use either for API's (https://auth0.com/docs/tokens) . It doesn't even make sense to since you have to validate a secure encrypted jwt before accessing further API functions. I don't know enough about auth0 to advise you further.

Comment: ahh that was helpful- thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with the Auth0 Community team and wanted to reach out. You can build out [scopes using Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/current) when an app requests permission to access a resource through an authorization server, it uses the scope parameter to specify what access it needs, and the authorization server uses the scope parameter to respond with the access that was actually granted (if the granted access was different from what was requested). From what I am reading it sounds like using [scopes and claims](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/current/sample-use-cases#request-custom-API-access) might be the direct goal here when working with a specific user. I hope this helps you on your path but if you have any questions please let me know!